# Banner slider script does not work properly in Safari, Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, slider

Below [link][1] has a banner(Sponsor logo's) slider script which works fine in IE 8, 9 & Firefox. But reduces the wrapper box size to very small portion which make banner almost invisible in all browser ( After i press Ctrl + F5).

and in case of Safari & chrome it some times show the banner when one visit the link or make the banner wrapper box very small.

I tried to play around & give fixed size but it keeps on overwriting the default height & width.

I would appreciate help on this

Safari, It works sometime in safari & sometime it behaves similar to Chrome browser. I tried to give fixed dimension used jQuery to give dimension on fly but problem keeps coming back.

RESOLVED ISSUE with following script when using carouFredSel, I used carouFredSel robot to generate the script which now works fine.

```
$("#SponsorSlider").carouFredSel({
    width: 610,
    height: 152,
    align: "left",
    padding: 0,
    items: {
        visible: 4,
        minimum: 4,
        width: "variable",
        height: "variable"
    },
    scroll: {
        fx: "fade",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED ISSUE with following script when using carouFredSel, I used carouFredSel robot to generate the script which now works fine.

```
$("#SponsorSlider").carouFredSel({
    width: 610,
    height: 152,
    align: "left",
    padding: 0,
    items: {
        visible: 4,
        minimum: 4,
        width: "variable",
        height: "variable"
    },
    scroll: {
        fx: "fade",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there must be some kind of configuration for the slider to set the good dimensions.
If you put a link to the slider you used, it would be easier.

However, if you don't find it, you can use the !important CSS hack : http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: I tried even using height & width, but it still have the same issue in different browser

Comment: !important hack works whatever the browser... If you need something more specific you should describe your issue more precisely!